# How do i create an online database and connect it to an android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

The main idea is to get daily updates for a topic and notify the user. Please suggest what services and databases to use (most secure) and the procedure/links on how to connect to the database.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your question is much too broad and I'm afarid you won't get an answer.
Consider making some research and then ask more concrete questions.

Comment: alright, just tell me how do I make a secure database so that my users or anyone else cant get to the contents

Answer (score 0):

Directly connecting to a database is not recommended at all. Instead you need to create service layer in a app server and consume the services from android. There are too many different ways and technologies for doing such things. You can set up your services and database in a server from scratch or you could use other solutions like Google Cloud App Engine, or use a Baas like Parse. These things provides services, storage and push notifications, among others.

You will need to read and investigate to find the most suitable for your case.